# Allow llvm/clang to see the text of enum tag?

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I currently have the following enums in C code. for example,

```
typedef enum {
  FIRST,
  SECOND,
  LAST
}
```

I am trying to do instrumentation on the tags and wrote a module pass through the C code. However, I notice that the enum tags are resolved into an integer already. It only displays as a number and the original text is gone. But I also want the name of the enums to show as well.

I was wondering if there is a trick to do this?

Thank you for the potential help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice task for [X Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLOR_TABLE \
X(red, "red")       \
X(green, "green")   \
X(blue, "blue")

#define X(a, b) a,
enum COLOR {
  COLOR_TABLE
};
#undef X

#define X(a, b) b,
char *color_name[] = {
  COLOR_TABLE
};
#undef X

int main() {
  enum COLOR c = red;
  printf("c=%s\n", color_name[c]);
  return 0;
}
```

Another way (using stringification):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLOR_TABLE \
X(red)   \
X(green) \
X(blue)

#define X(t) t,
enum COLOR {
  COLOR_TABLE
};
#undef X

#define X(t) #t,
char *color_name[] = {
  COLOR_TABLE
};
#undef X

int main() {
  enum COLOR c = red;
  printf("c=%s\n", color_name[c]);
  return 0;
}
```